# How to mock getCurrentLoginId in Spring security?

Tags: junit, spring-security

I am testing controller methods that include calls with:

```
SecurityUtils.getCurrentLoginId()
```

However, when I run this test

```
    SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
    Mockito.when(SecurityUtils.getCurrentLoginId()).thenReturn((long) 1);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post(uri)
            .with(user("admin").password("pass").roles("USER","ADMIN"))
            .with(csrf())
            .param("blogId", "" + blogId)
            .content(mapToJson(post))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User not found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mock static method, and Mockito doesn't support this feature. Please, use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) instead.

You will find some examples of mocking static methods via PowerMock [here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/blob/master/modules/module-test/easymock/junit4-test/src/test/java/samples/junit4/singleton/MockStaticTest.java).

Comment: I am trying to apply powermock with Mockito but when I add the PowerMockRunner.class - it looks like I lose the WebApplicaitonContext - what might be wrong?

Comment: the problem might be the RunWith losing the SpringTestRunner context

Comment: You are right - to enable Spring Context you have to run tests with Spring Junit Runner, and PowerMock requires its own runner to be enabled. In order to resolve this issue PowerMock provides @PowerMockRunnerDelegate. [Here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/JUnit_Delegating_Runner#using-powermock-with-junit-delegation-runner) you'll find explanation and some examples.

Comment: thanks, this works very nice: @RunWith( PowerMockRunner.class )
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)